# Chrome displays blank canvas, but displays fine on zoom in/out

Tags: google-chrome, canvas

In my single page (HTML/JS) app, the first screen is loaded using iframe. The contents of the iframe is a HTML page with canvas. The first time it loads in Chrome, the screen is blank. If I zoom in (or out) using CTRL+/- the contents of the canvas appears on screen.

This happens only from my laptop and only on Chrome (current version 51.0.2704.103 m). It works fine on Firefox (47.0.1) and IE11 in my machine. It also works fine from other desktops in my office.

Any pointers on what could be happening and how to fix it in Chrome?

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stacsuperuser.com.com/help/how-to-ask). You can flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it. As it stands your question would also be closed on [SO].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out the solution for this issue. Just disabling the hardware acceleration fixed it for me. In Chrome, go to Settings > (scroll down) Show Advanced Settings > System > uncheck the 'Use hardware acceleration when available' - and restart Chrome.

Just leaving this here for anyone facing the issue.